# target the <h4 id="name"> tag for the dynamically created divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a total beginner to jquery. and am badly stuck. i would really appreciate if i could get some help with my code.

The scenario is,
  - I have a drop down list for the names.
  - When i select a name from the list, it should display in the div which is placed beneath the drop down menu. The div will be created automatically via jquery. every item selected from the list will be displayed in its own respective div. The name Sarah should not be included in the drop down list.Its like a stand alone thing. However, when i select an item in the list, the name Sarah is replaced with the selected item.

What i was able to code was --
  - I could get the divs with some names associated with it. However, i am unable to target the selected item to its respective div.
  I hope it makes sense. I am posting the link to my jsFiddle. Please help.
http://jsfiddle.net/zohana28/0akosx2a/

```
<div class="part-4">
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
        <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="Oregano">Oregano</option>
        <option value="Thyme">Thyme</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!--end of part 4-->
<div class="main">
    <div class="part-2" id="click-1" style="cursor:pointer;">

        <div class="part-2-address">
             <h4 id="name">sarah</h4> 
        </div>

</div>
```

jQuery is:
     $(document).ready(function () {

```
      $(document).on('change', '#sel', function (e) {

        $('.part-3').html($('.part-2').html());

       $('.main').append('<div class = "part-3" > </div>');

       var str = $('select option:selected').text();
        $('#name').text(str);  
        console.log(str);


      });
  return false;

  });
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's how you want the result, but you can check http://jsfiddle.net/nukttgdj/

Comment: Thank you! i wanted the items to be listed in sequence. For example, Sarah should be at the top always, the items chosen should be at the bottom according to the item chosen. Like, Sarah, Then if i choose pepperoni, then the same under Sarah's name, then cheese and so on. Can you please look into it? Thank you again i really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6hmhnmL/) a bit.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('change', '#sel', function (e) {
      var nameTempl = '<div class="part-2" class="click-1">' 
          + '<div class="part-2-address">' 
          + '<h4 class="name">{name}</h4></div></div>';
      var str = $('select option:selected').text();
      $('.main').append(nameTempl.replace(/{name}/, str));
  });
  return true;
});
```

For the HTML: I removed the inline-style `cursor:pointer;` and added it as style for the class `.click-1` - previously `click-1` and name were `id`s, I've changed both to be classes. `id`s have to be unique, so you have to use classes instead.
Though it would be possible to `clone()` the `<div class="part-2" class="click-1">` and then change the name to the current selected option, I just preferred to use the target div as template in the function, with `{name}` as placeholder to be replaced with the current selected option: `nameTempl.replace(/{name}/, str)`.

Another adjustment that you can change back is - I've set the `height:200px;` of the `.main` div to  `min-height: 200px;`, so this container grows when necessary. You can just change this back to `height:200px;` in case you prefer the yellow div to have a static height like before.

As reference for `replace()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: thank you!! its perfect now. thanks for the link and explaining the code.

Comment: @Priyanka Glad I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed / solved. In case you don't know how this works and why this is useful, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235